# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fire'

Tags: python, flask

I am getting an error when I try to import a function from another python file in the same directory. When I remove the import the app runs fine. Can anyone tell my why I am getting the following import error?

I should add that i am running the app my running the start.sh file

**start.sh**

```
source venv/bin/activate
export FLASK_APP=myapp.py
flask run
```

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fire'**

**routes.py**

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from fire import fire

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    user = {'username': 'Miguelll'}
    posts = [
        {
            'author': {'username': 'John'},
            'body': 'Beautiful day in Portland!'
        },
        {
            'author': {'username': 'Susan'},
            'body': 'The Avengerss movie was so cool!'
        }
    ]
    print(fire())
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', user=user, posts=posts)
```

**fire.py**

```
import pyrebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "SNIP",
  "authDomain": "SNIP.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "SNIP",
  "storageBucket": "SNIP.appspot.com",
  "serviceAccount": "SNIP.json"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

def fire():
  auth = firebase.auth()
  #authenticate a user
  user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("SNIP@SNIP.com", "SNIPSNIPSNIP$")

  all_agents = db.child("items").get(user['idToken']).val()

  print(all_agents)
```

My Directory structure(Why is this image so big ha):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change my import to

```
from app.fire import fire
```